Getting testcontainers/ryuk from internal hub
Maybe someone has encountered this problem. I use testcontainers for unit and integration tests in Java. I need to run them on a stand in the internal network. But the problem is that the network does not have access to the Internet, and can only use internal resources. At the same time, testcontainers requires the testcontainers/ryuk image to work. How can I configure testcontainers so as to tell it where to load testcontainers/ryuk from?

You can use the ryuk.container.image property to instruct testcontainer to use a ryuk image from your internal docker image registry. See more details on this documentation page.
